# How to mapping jms with restful webservices?

Tags: java, rest, jms, tomcat7, jax-rs

I have created a RESTful service using JAX-RS Jersey and deployed it on a tomcat 7 server. 
Now in client Browser  got  request and response  synchronously,its working fine.But now i will change asynchronously(Request and Response),Could you please explain briefly with example.
Thanks and Regards,
Ramana

Comment: Do you mean that you are going to use AJAX? I might be wrong but believe that JMS is not what you are looking for.

Comment: not using Ajax,my question is i have developed restful webservices using jax-rs .using rest, client send one request only at time,but multiple clients sends the  request at time ,then how to handle this sitchivation?please explaine.

Comment: If you have implemented your solution the standard way, you don't have to worry about handling multiple client calls simultaneously at the server side. Tomcat will take care of that. Read up on how tomcat and Jersey works and let us know if it's still not working.